# How to make VI use spaces instead of tab even when I press backspace key?

Tags: tabs, vi, whitespace

When I tried to use `yml`, it requires NO TAB, ONLY SPACE policy.
I realized I need a special setting for this.

Anyway, I can't live without tabs. So I want to make my VI behave like this.

- When I press <kbd>tab</kbd> key, input many space characters aligned by tab stops.
- When I press <kbd>backspace</kbd> key, delete many space characters aligned by tab stops.

How can I archive this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

**Original vi:**
doesn't know about `et`, you could experiement with different values for `ts` (tabstop) and `sw` (shiftwidth, i.e. the amount `<<` and `>>` indent a line or block of text). Basically, whenever sw is set to something lower (usually a fraction of) the value assigned to ts, indenting will use spaces instead of tabs. Beware that when a multiple of shifts add up to a full tabstop, a tab will be used in that place.
Default is for both to be 8, and a number of other commands (such as expand), base their assumptions on that, so a text written with mixed tabs and spaces where ts has been tweaked may be misaligned when viewed lateron with a different setting for tabstop.
To achieve your goal, you could first use `/bin/expand` to replace all tabstops with spaces in your existing text, then pull the text into vi, `:set sw=4,ts=20`, and try if these settings suit you. If they do, you can make them permanent by writing them into your `.exrc`

Another way, which would allow you to use tab and backspace the way you prefer (instead of shifting with `<<` and `>>`) would be to allow yourself to write the text the way you prefer, and pipe it through `/bin/expand` prior to processing with yml, wither as part of your command chain, or from within vi itself:

```
:1,$!expand
```

**In vim:**
you can use the `et` (expandtab) setting as already suggested, and even convert all tabs into spaces by uning a builtin (which has the advantage of knowing your tabstop settings, incase you tweaked them, without having to be told explicitely, as `expand` needs to).

```
:set et|retab
```

other interesting settings would include `sts` (softtabstop) and `smarttab`, with all these settings adapted to suit your needs, even `ai` (autoindent) would behave consistently and throw spaces instead of tabs.

```
:set et
:set sw=3
:set sts=3
:set smarttab
:set ai
```

or, in one line:

```
:set et sw=3 sts=3 smarttab ai
```

Again, once you agree with these settings, place them in your `.vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

```
:set et
```

You'll have to give up <kbd>backspace</kbd> and use <kbd><</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> instead.

You might be able to map backspace to unindent but there might be undesirable consequences.